# JS Error: Variable not defined.... but it is

Tags: javascript

First of all, I apologize if this is a stupid question. It is very possible that I'm completely missing something trivial. I don't know what it is. So here's the problem:

(context: I'm making arbitrary precision math library in JavaScript)

Here's the code:

```
    function processInput(n){       
        let parts;
        let numer, denom, positivity;
        if(is.negative(n)){
            positivity = -1;
            n = n.substr(1);
        } else {
            positivity = 1;
        }
        ////////// RELEVANT SECTION STARTS ///////////////
        console.log(n); // prints "1 2/3", which is what I'm testing
        if(is.zero(n)){
            numer = [0], denom = [1], positivity = 0;
        } else if(is.mixedFrac(n)){
            console.log(n); // <------ error: "n is not defined". How???
            parts = n.match(/\d+/g).map(function(e){
                return ArrayOps.wholeToArnum(n);
            });
        ////////// RELEVANT SECTION ENDS ///////////////
            let w = parts[0], 
                n = parts[1],
                d = parts[2];
            let n1 = ArrayOps.multiply(w, d);
            numer = ArrayOps.add(n1, n);
            denom = d;
        } else if(is.frac(n)){
            parts = n.match(/\d+/g).map(function(e){
                return ArrayOps.wholeToArnum(e);    
            });
            numer = parts[0];
            denom = parts[1];
        } else if(is.repeatingDecimal(n)){
            let temp = n.split('...');
            let dec = ArrayOps.decToArnum(temp[0]);

            let decLength = dec.decLength;
            let repDec = ArrayOps.repDecToArnum(temp[1], decLength);

            let n1 = dec.numer;
            let d1 = dec.denom;
            let n2 = repDec.numer;
            let d2 = repDec.denom;
            n1 = ArrayOps.multiply(n1, d2);
            n2 = ArrayOps.multiply(n2, d1);
            numer = ArrayOps.add(n1, n2);
            denom = ArrayOps.multiply(d1, d2);
        } else if(is.decimal(n)){
            n = ArrayOps.decToArnum(n);
            numer = n.numer;
            denom = n.denom;
        } else if(is.wholeNum(n)){
            numer = ArrayOps.wholeToArnum(n);
            denom = [1];
        } else {
            throw new Error(`${n} is not a valid form of input.`);
        }
        return {numer, denom, positivity};
    }
```

(JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4mjwg57/3/)

Basically, this is what it comes down to:

```
function process(n){
  if(passTest(n)){
    console.log(n); // Error: "n is not defined"
  }
}
```

Here's the screenshot from debugging:
[image: n is defined.]

As I have highlighted in red rectangle, the debugger clearly shows `n = "1 2/3"`, and it passes the test (`is.mixedFrac(n)`), because it is mixed fraction.

There's nothing in `is.mixedFrac(n)` that can change `n`.

Continuing produces the following error: 
[image: The error]

If `n` wasn't defined in the first place, I shouldn't have passed the test. Can someone help me with what's going on? Again, I'm sure it's a trivial mistake. But I'm not seeing it.

Things to note:

- Changing the if control to `if(is.mixedFrac(n) && n)` still passes to inside the bracket
- I know screenshot is discouraged, but if you look at it, and I hover my mouse on `n` while on break point, it will still show that `n` is `"1 2/3"`.
- There is absolutely no async stuff going on. There's no timeout, ajax, promise, or anything going on. The entirety of my code is quite rudimentary.
- In FireFox, it gives me the following error: `` "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `n' before initialization" ``

Comment: Please add your code...so we can help you :-)

Comment: If JS says the variable is not definedd, then it is not defined. There are two common reasons, first being timing, i.e. trying to refer a variable before it is declared. The second is the scope, i.e. the referred variable is out of the scope of the referrer. Pick yours.

Comment: where is the method **mixedFrac**

Comment: are you able to `console.log(n)` just after the `function processInput(n){` ?

Comment: here is an example of why we need all code: https://jsfiddle.net/09yrcLqd/2/ (run and check the log)

Comment: Blame your IDE, it should have indicated that

Comment: @bambam this is happening in Chrome debugger.

Comment: Yeah, but your screenshots are from a IDE. Usually it should have indicated the duplicate declaration

Comment: you need to use `var` instead of `let` will solve your problem...

Comment: @bambam That's the job of a linter to find that. Not necessarily the IDE, and it's a rule you can turn off as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redeclared the variable `n` inside the same if statement (which is a block). `let` is block scoped, which means that `n` exists only within that block. But you've declared a variable with the same name as the scope above it, which overwrites it.

```
    ////////// RELEVANT SECTION STARTS ///////////////
    console.log(n); // prints "1 2/3", which is what I'm testing
    if(is.zero(n)){
        numer = [0], denom = [1], positivity = 0;
    } else if(is.mixedFrac(n)){
        console.log(n); // <------ error: "n is not defined". How???
        parts = n.match(/\d+/g).map(function(e){
            return ArrayOps.wholeToArnum(n);
        });
    ////////// RELEVANT SECTION ENDS ///////////////
        let w = parts[0], 
            n = parts[1], // HERE!
            d = parts[2];
        let n1 = ArrayOps.multiply(w, d)
```

```js
let n = [1,2,3]
if (true) {
 console.log(n)
 let n = 10
}
```

This is what you have essentially done. The `let n` declaration is now the only `n` that can exist in that block, and you've tried to `console.log` the variable before it has been declared.